# Using azure webapp as reverse proxy

Tags: azure, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to setup empty azure web app to be reverse proxy following exact same steps as described here: https://tomssl.com/2015/06/15/create-your-own-free-reverse-proxy-with-azure-web-apps/. First of all it seems that allowedservervariables can not be transformed, it is set to deny in application.config file. When i remove them i just get 404 not found when i try to access my webapp (HTTP Error 404.4 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for does not have a handler associated with it.).

Anyone have some suggestions?

Cheers

Comment: https://auth0.com/blog/building-a-reverse-proxy-in-dot-net-core/

Answer (score 0):

You should try Azure Function Proxies instead

https://markheath.net/post/azure-functions-v2-proxies

*A developer can create an Azure Function Proxy within the same UI as a Function App. Within the configuration, a developer will be asked to provide a Route template, identify which HTTP methods are allowed and provide a Backend URL where the HTTP request will be routed to. Backend URLs do not need to be static as you can dynamically set the URL based on content within the request or from your application settings.*

Comment: Thanks, I will try this approach, but i'm really interested in my original question, or if someone knows how can i debug it somehow...